# HTML cannot get menu in center of heading

Tags: html, css

I cant seem to figure out how to get the menu inline with the text in the heading which is in the centre of the heading already. I'm sure it isnt a difficult problem but i cant figure it out as im trying to teach myself.
Any help would be appreciated.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
}
#toplocation {
  background-color: black;
  color: grey;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#heading {
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}
#redline {
  background-color: #ff0a0a;
  height: 2px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
}
ul#menu li a {
  background-color: #383838;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0a0a;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div id="toplocation">
  <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>
  (01)-8393790&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <i class="fa fa-map-  marker">&nbspBaldoyle Industrial Estate</i>
</div>
<div id="heading">
  <h3>Kilbride Classic Cuisine 
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="news.asp">Products</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.asp">MyOwn Gym Foods</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.asp">Contact Us</a></li> 
 </ul>
  </h3>
</div>
<div id="redline"></div>
```

Comment: Can you put your code in a `jsFiddle` or similar to show us the issue, please?

Comment: Your description seems vague. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Not sure what to do with that mate, havent used it before

Comment: At the moment, the menu is under the text kcc, where as i want it to the right of it, inline with the text or in the centre of the heading

Comment: @Dylan : Just adding `display: inline` to `ul#menu` will do the trick. Check my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ? Making a few guesses from your description.

```css
html,body
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden; 
font-family: sans-serif, arial;
}



#toplocation
{
background-color:black;
color:grey;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
}

#heading
{
background-color:#2b2b2b;
color:white;
padding-top: 14px;
padding-right: 14px;
padding-bottom: 14px;
padding-left: 14px;

}
#redline
{
background-color:#ff0a0a;

height: 2px;
border: 0;
padding: 0; 
}
.pull-left{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:100px;
  }
.h2{
  font-size:22px;
  }

ul#menu {
padding: 0;
}

ul#menu li {
display: inline;

}

ul#menu li a {
background-color: #383838;
color: white;
padding: 4px 11px;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
background-color: #ff0a0a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-            awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HomepageStyleSheet.css">
<title>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="toplocation">
    <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>
    (01)-8393790&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="fa fa-map-  marker">&nbspBaldoyle Industrial Estate</i>
  </div>
 <div id="heading">
    <div class="h2">
      <span class="pull-left">Kilbride Classic Cuisine </span>
    <ul id="menu">

        <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.asp">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp">MyOwn Gym Foods</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="redline"></div>
```

Comment: That's the kind of thing im looking for mate, thanks. How do i go about adding more space between it and the text?

Comment: @Dylan: Use margin like `margin-left: 20px` to `ul`

Comment: You can give margin right to the heading element. I have updated the code. It will look clean in large proper screen.

Comment: The best option depending on your element width and number of items , is to `float:left` the heading and `float:right` the menu. Both will produce same result

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**
Is that what you want?

```css
html,body
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden; 
font-family: sans-serif, arial;
}



#toplocation
{
background-color:black;
color:grey;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
h3{float:left;margin:12px 10px;}

#heading
{
background-color:#2b2b2b;
color:white;
padding-top: 14px;
padding-right: 14px;
padding-bottom: 14px;
padding-left: 14px;
}
#redline
{
background-color:#ff0a0a;

height: 2px;
border: 0;
padding: 0; 
}
ul#menu {
padding: 0;
}

ul#menu li {
display: inline;

}

ul#menu li a {
background-color: #383838;
color: white;
padding: 4px 11px;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
background-color: #ff0a0a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-            awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HomepageStyleSheet.css">
<title>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="toplocation">
    <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>
    (01)-8393790&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="fa fa-map-  marker">&nbspBaldoyle Industrial Estate</i>
  </div>
 <div id="heading">
    <h3>Kilbride Classic Cuisine </h3>
    <ul id="menu">

        <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.asp">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp">MyOwn Gym Foods</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>

</div>
<div id="redline"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your really shouldn't put the `ul` inside the `h3`.

Then to align the Heading `h3` and menu, set them both to `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle;`.

The menu and heading will then line up **provided there is enough room for both on the same line.**

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zBoedy)

```css
#toplocation {
  background-color: black;
  color: grey;
  padding: 5px;
}

#heading {
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px;
}

#heading h3 {
  display: inline-block;
}


ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
}

ul#menu li a {
  background-color: #383838;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0a0a;
}
```

```html
<div id="toplocation">
    <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>
    (01)-8393790 <i class="fa fa-map-marker"> Baldoyle Industrial Estate</i>
  </div>
 <div id="heading">
   <h3>Kilbride Classic Cuisine </h3>
    <ul id="menu">

        <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.asp">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp">MyOwn Gym Foods</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">Contact Us</a></li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, I've fixed your code: https://jsfiddle.net/geof9LuL/2/

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
}

#toplocation {
  background-color: black;
  color: grey;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#heading {
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-left: 14px;
}

#redline {
  background-color: #ff0a0a;
  height: 2px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
}

ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
}

ul#menu li a {
  background-color: #383838;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0a0a;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-container {
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-            awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HomepageStyleSheet.css">
    <title>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="toplocation">
      <i class="fa fa-fax"></i> (01)-8393790&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
      <i class="fa fa-map-  marker">&nbspBaldoyle Industrial Estate</i>
    </div>
    <div id="heading">
      <h3 class="title">Kilbride Classic Cuisine</h3>
      <div class="menu-container">
        <ul id="menu">

          <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></lai>
          <li><a href="news.asp">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.asp">MyOwn Gym Foods</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.asp">Contact Us</a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="redline"></div>
```

Also, in your example you had the menu inside the `<h3>` which isn't valid.

Answer (score 0):

The `ul#menu` and the `h3` tag both should be declared as `display: inline`.

Try to avoid to do something in the `<h3>`-tag expect text because some search-engines are looking for those tags and use them.

```
<h3>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</h3>
<ul id="menu">...</ul>
```

For the `<div id="heading">` you could use the new html tag `<header id="heading">`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: inline` to your `ul#menu` should do the trick.

`margin-left: 20px;` to have spacing between heading and menu.

Modified `ul#menu` as below

```
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
```

---

**Here is the full Snippet:**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif, arial;
}
#toplocation {
  background-color: black;
  color: grey;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
#heading {
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#redline {
  background-color: #ff0a0a;
  height: 2px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: inline;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
}
ul#menu li a {
  background-color: #383838;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #ff0a0a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-            awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HomepageStyleSheet.css">
  <title>Kilbride Classic Cuisine</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="toplocation">
    <i class="fa fa-fax"></i>
    (01)-8393790&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <i class="fa fa-map-  marker">&nbspBaldoyle Industrial Estate</i>
  </div>
  <div id="heading">
    <h3>Kilbride Classic Cuisine
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="news.asp">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.asp">MyOwn Gym Foods</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.asp">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="redline"></div>
</body>
```